# In PCA, why does maximising projections maximise variance?

Tags: pca, eigenvalues, projection

My understanding could be wrong as the lecture series from my University isn't clear and there are no links to share.

But having rewatched a few times, I think the point being made is:

. We want the Eigen vectors that account for the most information. This is done through finding the eigen vectors which have the largest projections.

For starters, is my assumption even correct? Or was it that we want ones where projections have maximal variance?

If my assumption is correct, then why does the maximum projection distance imply high infomration

Comment: Maximal variance, I believe. What do you mean by maximum projection distance